# To get Month Name in place of Table Name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following MONTH wise tables...

- vbSuccessfulCDR_597
- vbSuccessfulCDR_598
- vbSuccessfulCDR_599
- vbSuccessfulCDR_600
- vbSuccessfulCDR_601 and so on..

Following query gives me the table list.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'vbSuccessfulCDR_%';
```

I want to see month name as output in another column which corresponds to the TABLE_NAME since I know **vbSuccessfulCDR_597** represents January'2021 **vbSuccessfulCDR_598** represents February'2021 and so on... This will help me to search date range from different tables.

Is there any way to get month name in place of table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `TIMESTAMPADD()` function here:

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH,
                    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TABLE_NAME, '_', -1) AS UNSIGNED) - 597,
                    '2021-01-01') AS month
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'vbSuccessfulCDR_%';
```

Comment: Getting an Error while executing.
Error Code: 1690. BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(cast(substring_index(`information_schema`.`TABLES`.`TABLE_NAME`,'_',-(1)) as unsigned) - 597)

Comment: How big can the numbers get?

Comment: started from 597 and now it is 633 which will increment 1 at every month.

Comment: I suspect that you have some bad table names matching the query, which are breaking the logic.